# How can I load the entire page using PJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

Is it possible to load the entire page using **PJAX** and change the browser's page url?

My purpose is to prepare first the response to make sure that it would be loaded without refreshing the page in a long time after clicking in the menu-page-link or execute a javascript function.

I tried using **PJAX** but the one that provides a response data for the selected element to load where the request has to display.

Like:

```
$('a').pjax("#container", { fragment: "#container" });
```

I want and I tried:

```
$('a').pjax({url:"new-page.html"});
```

But it didn't work.

I'll appreciate your help and suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: It almost sounds like you just want to disable pjax for one of the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible using [jquery PJAX plugin](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) , you can keep the header footer static and change the body content using PJAX , and yes it will change the url too along with browser history stack i.e. almost making it like a normal navigation, except that page wouldn't be refreshed.
  But the container needs to be same in both the urls. You can try :

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load page via ajax but you cannot change page url, when you change it, it will automatic redirect to that address. This prevent phishing page, fake url.... But why you need to load page via ajax then change the url, why don't just change the url?

Comment: As I said, to render or prepare first the response to make sure that it would be loaded without refreshing the page in a long time.

Comment: @napstyrmaceda, please be more specific.  Maybe there's a way of doing this without using ajax to load the entire page.